# Jobs minor design issue when showing too many tags

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I accidentally did a copy paste into the tags you like in the "tech you like" in the job filters and hit enter.  It put in some words and allowed me to click "View More" to see all the tags I typed in.

It cuts it off at the bottom, not sure if it is worth making larger - being that I copied and pasted some wrong text.  Thought I'd point it out that I cannot see the bottom of them.

[image]